# Why doesn't this code loop forever with a break label?

Tags: go

I am trying to figure out how break with labels works.

I expect the following program to keep printing "In if statement" forever. This is because the `break here` statement brings the code execution back up to the beginning for loop which should then be executed again and again.

However, this code is only executed once. What am I missing here?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
here:
    for {
        fmt.Println("In if statement")
        break here

    }
    fmt.Println("At the bottom")
}
```

Execution result:

```
In if statement
At the bottom

Program exited.
```

http://play.golang.org/p/y9kH1YZezJ

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This is because the break here statement brings the code execution back up to the beginning for loop

No, that is not what break does. It is not a goto. It *exits* the loop marked with the label. Execution continues *after* the loop.

In this particular example, the label is unneccessary, you would be getting the same result by breaking out of the innermost loop by default (without a label).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. I understand now. If I used `goto here` instead of `break here` I would get the effect I originally expected.

Answer (score 9):

From the go specification on [break statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Break_statements):

> If there is a label, it must be that of an enclosing "for", "switch", or "select" statement, and **that is the one whose execution terminates**.

The `break` statement doesn't bring your code back to the label, it close the loop referenced by the label. So everything is working fine…

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I selected Thilo's because it helped me figure out that `goto here` and `break here` do different things in the context of loops.